# Slide mobile menu left, then down with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slide, slidetoggle

I'm trying to have a mobile menu slide from right and then slide down. I was able to do this, but I also need it to slide back up and to the right on second click. However, it just does this simultaneously and after this click it no longer does these animations in order. The code is below. I need to fix it so that during menu open : 1. slides left, 2. drops down. During menu close: 1.slides/wraps up, 2.slides right.

```
$(".mobile-menu-toggler").click(function (){
$(this).removeClass('mobile-menu-toggler');
$(this).addClass('mobile-menu-toggler-clicked');
$("#mainmenu-mobile").toggle({direction:'left'},700).animate({'height':'100%'},700);
});

$(".mobile-menu-toggler-clicked").click(function (){
$(this).removeClass('mobile-menu-toggler-clicked');
$(this).addClass('mobile-menu-toggler');
$("#mainmenu-mobile").toggle({direction:'left'},700).animate({'height':'0'},700);
});
```

P.S. I tried using `.show` and `.hide` instead of `.toggle`. It would show, but then it would not hide.

CSS:

```
#mainmenu-mobile-wrap {
display: block;
position: fixed;
top:0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1000;

height: 100%;
}

#mainmenu-mobile {
display: none;
float: right;
width: 280px;
height: 0;
}

#mobile-menu-toggler{
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
background: red;
float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uptjwuaj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution:

*(if that's what you wanted, because I don't know if I understood you well)*

```
$open=false;
$(".mobile-menu-toggler").click(function (){
    if($open==false){
        $("#mainmenu-mobile").toggle({direction:'left'},700).animate({'height':'100%'},700);
        $open=true;
    }else{
        $("#mainmenu-mobile").animate({'height':'0'},700).toggle({direction:'left'},700);
        $open=false;
    }
});
```

And here is jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/3bmduf55/

Comment: exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply alternate the delay depending on the menu state (I've stored it in dataset) + some changes in your CSS:

```js
var $mobMenuWrap = $('#mainmenu-mobile-wrap');
var $mobMenuTog = $('#mobile-menu-toggler');
var $mobMenu = $('#mainmenu-mobile');

$mobMenuTog.click(function (){
  var io = this.dataset.io ^= 1; // I/O Toggler
  $mobMenuWrap.delay(io?0:700).animate({right:io?0:-280},700);
  $mobMenu.delay(io?700:0).slideToggle(700);
});
```

```css
#mainmenu-mobile-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  right: -280px;
  width: 280px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#mainmenu-mobile {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:none;
  background:#ddd;
}

#mobile-menu-toggler{
  position:absolute;
  left: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainmenu-mobile-wrap">
  <div id="mobile-menu-toggler" class="mobile-menu-toggler"></div>
  <div id="mainmenu-mobile">
    <ul>
      <li>1111111</li>
      <li>22222222222222</li>
      <li>3333333333333</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```